# Programmatically calling cmd.exe from MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, command-prompt

I’m facing some issue w.r.t calling a .exe from MVC4.
I have a ActionResult method where I want to start a command prompt locally but it shouldnot run as IISPool Identity instead it should run as a user logged in, unlike we do RunAs manually.
I have to pass parameter to the command line and in turn receive the output. I have written a code but it is not returning anything. Can someone highlight where I made some mistake.

```
string _commandParameter = @"whoami";
            try
            {

                var process = new Process
                {
                    StartInfo =
                                {
                                    CreateNoWindow = true,
                                    UseShellExecute = false,
                                    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                                    RedirectStandardInput = true,
                                    RedirectStandardError = true,
                                    Verb = "runas",
                                    FileName = @"C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe",                                    
                                    Domain = "dir",
                                    UserName = userID,
                                    Password = GetSecureString(userpassword),
                                    Arguments = _commandParameter 
                                }
                };
                process.Start();

                string readToEndOutput = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
                string readToEndError = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();

                process.WaitForExit();
}
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                log.Info("error as StackTrace Exception in Input ActionResult  -" + ex.StackTrace.ToString());
                log.Info("error as Message Exception in Input ActionResult -" + ex.Message.ToString());
            }
public static SecureString GetSecureString(string str)
        {
            SecureString result = new SecureString();
            try
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str))
                    return null;
                else
                {
                    foreach (char c in str.ToCharArray())
                        result.AppendChar(c);
                    return result;

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                log.Info("Cannot create password-" + ex.StackTrace.ToString());

            }
            return result;
        }
```

The output

[image]

Comment: "start a command prompt locally" - what do you mean by locally? You know `whoami` is never going to be different right?

Comment: Have you tried first wait for exit and then reading the streams?

Comment: "locally" in this case means the prompt would open *on the server*. You want to read input from a command prompt *on the server* ?

Comment: MVC will run on server so this code will start cmd on server not on machine from which user access your page

Comment: `but it is not returning anything` - How could it? Your code basically does nothing. What do you expect `cmd.exe` to do? Do you expect it to read AD account info/verify user credentials? Please state *exactly* what you are trying to achieve. I doubt very much that a command prompt is the proper way to do what you want.

Comment: If you are using windows authentication and just want what the command "whoami" would return for the current user, simply use `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name`.

Comment: You are correct this is a web application. I try to describe a flow.
1. There is a button where user would click.

Comment: You are correct this is a web application.I try to describe a flow.
1. There is a button where user would click from anywhere.
2. Upon clicking the button it would take the user credentials & invoke a command prompt with user credential in the server.
3. arguments will be a string which will be a command line agrument. e.g powershell.exe c:\diskerr\\cred.ps1 -command C:\disk\disk.ps1'-Server test -Volumeletter D: -deltasize 1 -Logfile c:\diskextension\op.txt' 
4. Activity in point 2 the command prompt needs to be opened using user's credential & the command to be executed is in point 4

Comment: 1. Want to open command prompt using user's credential from ActionMethod in MVC
2. execute the powershell.exe c:\diskerr\\cred.ps1 -command C:\disk\disk.ps1'-Server test -Volumeletter D: -deltasize 1 -Logfile c:\diskextension\op.txt'  in command line.
Could you please let me know how to achieve my goal.

Comment: when I checked eventviewer I'm getting this error below
Faulting application name: cmd.exe, version: 10.0.14393.0, time stamp: 0x57899a99
Faulting module name: KERNEL32.DLL_unloaded, version: 10.0.14393.1198, time stamp: 0x59028368
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x0000000000019bf0
Faulting process id: 0x2108
Faulting application start time: 0x01d3858cc3eb8fee
Faulting application path: C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe
Faulting module path: KERNEL32.DLL
Report Id: cca8a6ee-8b2b-4c87-87d7-38e5609f2942
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:

Comment: Instead of launching a shell that executes a powershell script which returns whatever, why don't you simply "translate" your PS commands into proper C# that can be executed directly from the controller? Don't leave your box if you don't have to.

Comment: Thanks for your response but I have already done it but we are facing issues with it so I'm trying to invoke the command prompt RunAs and execute it in command line

Comment: `we are facing issues` - Then let's rather fix *these* issues instead. In order to achieve what you want via command prompt, you would need to run that prompt via impersonation/delegation as that user. But in order to properly do so, you need that user's account information - which is what you try to achieve with command prompt. You see, before you can run the command prompt you need the kind of info you try to *get* from the command prompt, so let's just ditch that right away and do it the proper way.

Comment: Sorry I failed to understand what you mean. The whoami is to test that under which credentials the command prompt has been invoked. The actual argument would be invoking poweshell script through command prompt but using impersonation.

Comment: Your impersonation would need FullTrust - which you won't get running from MVC. Probably not going to work this way. Better try to translate your PS commands to C#. Update your question so we can help you.